# Motherboard controllers

Tags: controller, motherboard

Is there a way to find out all the controllers the motherboard can access (ie: DMA, UART, IDE) without actually looking at the motherboard board? Sorry if it sounds silly, but I just discovered the UART (had to write a windows driver for it) and I'm just curious

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to "look at the motherboard board?" I mean, Are you saying you don't want to do a deep technical analysis of the board? Or do you not even want to know who built it? In other words, is "look at the manual for the motherboard" an acceptable answer? Or do you need software that can give you the information you want?

Comment: I don't want to look at the motherboard because there are chances that:
1. I don't understand the purpose of a component (eg: I look at the component number and that number doesn't "say" anything to me);
2. I break the seal (and the warranty) of the PC.

Yes, a software or the manufacturer datasheet might solve my problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the important information from the manufacturer of the motherboard.  Intel, for one, provides a datasheet for each motherboard they design on their website.  Other motherboard manufacturers will sometimes even provide schematics.  Doing it this way is much more reliable than just looking at the motherboard.